# My texture isn't working with my baked normal

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

I created my own normal but when I add a texture from [Poliigon](https://www.poliigon.com/texture/metal-corroded-heavy-001), it looks really blotchy and weird. How do I get my texture to look more natural with the normal I baked?

Here's a copy of the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CaOtMp7PLY_wtZe7TV00ynI1tMJTXoDK/view?usp=sharing

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong model. The image shows your high poly, which is not (and does not need to be, because that's why you bake to a low poly) unwrapped. Your low poly model is on another layer.
The texture should go on your low poly. Then it looks fine.

[image]